# Why do some musicians/groups create a last track with tons of silence in the middle?

Tags: music

I've seen this at least four times. An album with the usual 4/5 minute songs has a last track of about 15 minutes, of which 10 are silence in the middle of the track.

Is there a meme I'm not aware of? Is it a reference to something?

Answer (score 5):

It's called a [hidden track](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_track).

Back in the day when CDs first came out, many artists put an extra song on the CD that was not available on the cassette version.  It was probably a marketing thing to get people to buy the CDs.

Later when CDs were more popular, some CDs started including a hidden track in the manner you described in your question.  Some are placed as a surprise or joke.  This could have started because a typical CD only includes about 45 minutes worth of music, but has a capacity of well over an hour and costs the same to produce no matter how full it is.

Comment: Another thing some bands did was burn 99 tracks on the CD, the album first, then a hidden track on one of the remaining blank tracks. I think The Stone Roses did that on one of their albums.

Comment: Nine Inch Nails - Broken EP has 99 tracks. 
Tool - Undertow has 69 tracks.